# Trouble making basic java program to count your number of clicks

Tags: java

why doesn't this work correctly? i cant seem to find the problem
its suppose to increment the text display by one for each time the button is clicked

```
public class ClickerGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public ClickerGame() {
            initComponents();
        }

        //declare
        int clicks;
        String clicksout = "" + clicks;

        //Swing GUI netbeans code is here, removed because it is irrelevant

    //click increments number by 1
        private void clickActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
            clicks++;
            clickercounter.setText(clicksout);
        }                                     

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new ClickerGame().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton click;
        private javax.swing.JTextField clickercounter;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You only set `clicksout` once:

```
String clicksout = "" + clicks;
```

The value isn't reset dynamically if `clicks` change. If you never change it, you'll always get the same result here:

```
clickercounter.setText(clicksout);
```

Try this instead:

```
clickercounter.setText("" + clicks);
```

You won't need `clicksout` as a separate variable.